# Static content in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to load the static content for my Django which I have upgraded to Django 1.4 
The project has been successfuly deployed , but I am unable to find the images and all the static content of the project.

Please find the settings.py file

```
# Django settings for DataEntry project.
import sys
import os
from path import path

SETTINGS_FILE_FOLDER = path(__file__).parent.abspath()

sys.path.append(SETTINGS_FILE_FOLDER.joinpath("libs").abspath())


DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
INTERNAL_IPS = ("127.0.0.1", "localhost", "192.168.100.102")

ADMINS = (
    (" Hello World ", "hello.world@gmail.com"),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'gototest',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'root',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        'OPTIONS': {
               "init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB",
        }
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SETTINGS_FILE_FOLDER,'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = '/static'
STATIC_PATH = '/static'
UPLOAD_DIR =  '/Users/iceman/Documents/gototest/qbank/static/uploads'
SITE_NAME = 'demo.com'
SITE_URL = 'http://alphadev.demo.com'

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'core.UserProfile'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/students/login/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''
#STATIC_ROOT = '/Users/iceman/Documents/gototest/qbank/static'
# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = ' hidden '

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
#    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
#    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
     'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
     'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    #'utils.XhtmlMortifierMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
#simplCACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   SETTINGS_FILE_FOLDER.joinpath("../templates"),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    #'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    #'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'accounts.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',

    'core',
    'tinymce',
    'filebrowser',
    'tagging',
    'tagging_autocomplete',
    'django_extensions',
    'registration',
    'questionmanager',
    'corporate',
)

ADMIN_HASH_SECRET = " "

RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = " "
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = " "

SERIALIZATION_MODULES = { 'modeljson' : 'wadofstuff.django.serializers.json' }
SOLR_ROOT = "http://dev.demo.com:8080/QuestionSolr"

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",

    "utils.context_processor",
    "qutils.context_processor",
)

#'plugins': "table,paste,searchreplace,safari,asciimath,contextmenu",

TINYMCE_JS_URL = "/static/tinymce/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" 
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT ="/static/tinymce/tiny_mce"
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "table,asciimath,gototest,indicime",
    'mode' : "textareas",
    'theme': "advanced",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
    'theme_advanced_buttons1' : "fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,sub,sup,separator,cut,copy,paste,undo,redo",
    'theme_advanced_buttons2' : "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,numlist,bullist,outdent,indent,separator,forecolor",
    'theme_advanced_buttons3' : "gototest,backcolor,separator,hr,link,unlink,image,table,code,separator,asciimath,asciimathcharmap,indicime",

    'theme_advanced_fonts' : "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif,Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace,Georgia=georgia,times new roman,times,serif,Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,Times=times new roman,times,serif,Verdana=verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' : "top",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' : "left",
    'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' : "bottom",
    'tab_focus' : ':prev,:next',

}

#'content_css' : "/static/css/content.css",

TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = False
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True

FORCE_LOWERCASE_TAGS = True

MARKITUP_FILTER = ('markdown.markdown', {'safe_mode': True}) 
MARKITUP_SET = 'markitup/sets/markdown'
MARKITUP_SKIN = 'markitup/skins/markitup'
MARKITUP_MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
MARKITUP_AUTO_PREVIEW = True
JQUERY_URL = '/static/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'
TAGGING_AUTOCOMPLETE_JS_BASE_URL = "/static"



try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError: pass
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

When I am looking for the images on the browser URL = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/site_img/logo.gif`

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/site_img/logo.gif
"/Users/iceman/Documents/gototest/qbank/qbank/static/site_img/logo.gif" does not exist
```

Comment: What are you using as your webserver? Django's built in? Nginx + gunicorn/uwsgi? Apache + modwsgi? You also don't seem to have a [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) value set

Comment: I have uncomented the `STATIC_ROOT` it is still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anwer your specific problem, i thing your STATICFILES_DIRS key is missing.

This appear to be your debug config file, so I suppose you want to serve your files with django built-in developement web server (ie: doing "manage.py runserver 8000")

**1. DEBUG=True|False**

You must know that django should not be used to serve files in production and will refuse to do so.
If you have "DEBUG=False", django will refuse to serve static files by default.

You have to use another server (most people use nginx, or an online cloud service, like cloudfront for this)

For this there is a 2 step process
1. You need to collect static files
2. Set up another server to serve them

When developping this is not convenient, so django look into STATICFILES_DIRS for you, and serve static files

**2. Collecting files**

A django website is made of multiple applications (see "INSTALLED_APPS" key in your config).
Each one of them may declare static files, all in different directories in your filesystem.

For your files to be properly served, you need them to be grouped in a single local directory, or a single remote server, hence the "./manage.py collectstatic".

This command will scan every directory listed in STATICFILES_DIRS and every "static" directory in loaded applications, and then copy files to the place you want with STATICFILES_STORAGE and STATIC_ROOT)

**3. Config keys**

```
# Tells django where your static files are
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../static/generated'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../static/fixed'),
)

# Only for developpement
# Tells to django build in web server where to host your files ("http://localhost/static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# for production, tell django how do {% static %} template tags and "./manage collectstatic" behave (collect files to a single directory, upload them to a CDN, etc)
# 
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

# Only for production when using default value for STATICFILES_STORAGE
# Tell django where to collect files when you run "./manage.py collectstatic".
# This is only used if you host your static files in the same machine as the rest of your application
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static.mydomain.com/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [STATICFILES_FINDERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-storage) and [STATICFILES_STORAGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-storage) (for deployment) to your settings file.

This will make your life much easier in Django: you put a static folder in each of your apps for when you develop, and when you deploy, you run the [collect_static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) command on your project and all the statics from all the apps will be gathered in the folder specified in the `STATICFILES_STORAGE` settings.

In the deployment environment, the `STATICFILES_STORAGE` should be served by the web server.